# I have Error when running the NPM "request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.url"

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, npm, compiler-errors, npx

I ran into the Error when trying to set up the React Environment in VScode.

PS T:\Data\MaiNgo\UI_webshare> npm install create-react-app
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.url
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mai.ngo\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-28T20_39_37_179Z-debug-0.log

I looked up the solution in stackoverflow but I have not found anything that related to my issues.

I tried
npm config set proxy "http://proxy.url:port/"
npm config set https-proxy "http://proxy.url:port/"
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm install create-react-app

and

npm config get registry

The problem still not solved. I need to use npm create-react-app as Front-End to built the UI which connects to PHP as Back-End.